# How to avoid type specification in a WCF request from .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I am calling a WCF method in a service not controlled by me. The call is made from a .Net app developed in Visual Studio. In the service wsdl-file there is an element without type:

```
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Number" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:element name="Code"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

In the generated request class, the element named "Code" is the of type object. If the service method is called, an exception is thrown with because xsi:type="xsd:string" is added to the "Code"-element (when a string is written to the element. This is not added to the "Number"-element since its type is defined in the wsdl. The validation of the server side is out of my hands. I tested to modify the type of the "Code"-element in the request object to string instead of object. Doing that that call is made without any errors. Is there a way to force the xml serialization to skip type definition in the request object without modifying the auto-generated request object?

Comment: I think you can serialize the SOAP message yourself, I demonstrated how to serialize the SOAP message in WCF in this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026546/wcf-sending-object-from-messageinspector-to-operation-method/62037961#62037961